# select all checkboxes at a particular time in html or js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am in need of having a3 checkboxes that should have a tick mark from 2 pm till 11 pm IST in javascript or HTML. This is what I tried

```html
<html>
<body>
<center>
<span style="margin-left:50px; margin-top:0px;">
   <p align="left"><font color="white"> <b> India Time: 2pm to 11pm IST </b>
  
  </br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="user1" name="user1" value="user1" > User1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="user2" name="user2" value="user2" > User2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="user3" name="user3" value="user3" > User3<br>
  </p>
  <img border="1" src="https://i.postimg.cc/VkPzvHCJ/gh.png" style=" margin-top:-129px;" >
</span>


<h3 style= "font-family: "Gotham A","Gotham B",sans-serif;>
 <br> <p align="center" style=" margin-top:-30px;"> <font color="#339933"> <b>RStudio Dashboard 
</h3></P> 
</body>
<script>
 var today = new Date();
 var dd = today.getDate();
 var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0! 
 var yyyy = today.getFullYear(); 
 if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} 
 if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} 
 var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
var holidays = [];
holidays = ["01/01/2019" , "26/01/2019" , "20/02/2019" , "01/05/2019" , "27/05/2019" , "04/06/2019", "04/07/2019" , "15/08/2019" , "02/09/2019" , "10/09/2019" , "02/10/2019" , "28/11/2019" , "25/12/2019"];
//var n = str.indexOf("welcome");
if {
  var startTime = '2:00 PM';
    var endTime = '11:00 PM';

    var curr_time = getval();
     //var curr_time = '12:39 AM';
    //alert(curr_time);
    

    if (get24Hr(curr_time) > get24Hr(startTime) && get24Hr(curr_time) < get24Hr(endTime)) {
      //in between these two times
      //alert("Yes")

      document.getElementById("sid").checked = true;
      document.getElementById("anil").checked = true;
      document.getElementById("vin").checked = true;
      
      
     
    } else {
     //document.getElementById("user1").checked = true;
     //document.getElementById("user2").checked = true;
    }

    function get24Hr(time){
      var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
      var AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
      if(AMPM == "PM" && hours<12) hours = hours+12;
      if(AMPM == "AM" && hours==12) hours = hours-12;

      var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
      hours = hours*100+minutes;
      console.log(time +" - "+hours);
      return hours;
 }

    function getval() {
     var currentTime = new Date()
     var hours = currentTime.getHours()
     var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

     if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;

     var suffix = "AM";
     if (hours >= 12) {
        suffix = "PM";
        hours = hours - 12;
     }
     if (hours == 0) {
        hours = 12;
     }
     var current_time = hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix;

     return current_time;

    }
}
else
{
print ("hello")
}

</script>

</html>
```

This is what I tried. The code is working, but it seems a bit complicated. Is there any simple method?
The only requirement is to tick the checkboxes from 2 pm to 11 pm IST

Comment: your html is invalid

Answer (score -1):

Add this js function. And then add "onClick" on every Input. Also the name must be the same.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  function toggle(source) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('user');
    for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
      checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
  }
</script>

<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" id="user1" name="user" value="user1" > User1<br>
<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" id="user2" name="user" value="user2" > User2<br>
<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" id="user3" name="user" value="user3" > User3<br>
```